# C++ CMD input along with exe

Tags: c++, input, cmd, user-input

Sorry for such a noobie question, but how can I get a program to read the data i input with my program, like how cmd does it with the options

```
shutdown.exe -f
```

how do i read the example `-f` into my program?

Answer (score 1):

This should print out each of the whitespace delimited parameters which were passed to your program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're always outputting argv [0].

Answer (score 0):

If you're using plain old C++, your main function will need to look something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

where argc is the number of whitespace separated items, and argv is an array of pointers to each one

Comment: cool ! Thanks! I should have given a better example though. my program needs both strings and integer inputs, so char wont quite cut it, unless im reading you wrong

Comment: you can simply atoi the number. So if you've got a number as the first one, int n = atoi (argv [0]);

Comment: Sorry, I meant int n = atoi (argv [1]);
Note that argv [0] will contain the actual program command

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

}
```

arguments are passed by `argv`.